# Keyboard shortcut for running current cell but not moving cursor to next one in Jupyter for VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using visual studio code and the jupyter functionality and I want to run the current cell **without going to the next cell nor creating a new cell**. Just run the current cell and keep the cursor there (don't automatically move to the next one nor create one).

I tried:

`Command + Enter`

and

`alt + Enter`

but both seem to move me to the next cell. Anyone know how to fix this? I only want to run the current cell and stay in it. Nothing more.

Answer (score 9):

Windows: `Ctrl + Enter`

Mac: `control + return`

Answer (score 1):

You can change the settings from keyboard shortcuts. Its default is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>. You can change it directly <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>